# How to prevent sub-lists numbering restart under each bullet?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

Google doc's numbered list functionality restarts sub-list "numbering" or "sequential lettering" like this:

```
1) First thing
   a)
   b)
2) Second thing
   a) <- Sub-list numbering / sequential letters restarts
   b)
```

I want it not to restart, and to rather act like this:

```
1) First thing
   a)
   b)
2) Second thing
   c) <- Sub-list does not restart
   d)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to **Restart numbering...** 2x:

[image]

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, but removes the ability to be able to add more entries in a previous category without needing to repeat this solution. This is a good technique to use after a list has been completed, but I guess I am looking for a more dynamic solution. For example, With your method if I were to add another bullet under "first thing", it would be "c)", but the lettering in the next category would still start with "c)" instead of "d)"

Comment: @JohnHadish unfortunately, this is the only way how to accomplish it